# How do I use a value from a wrapper function in a decorated function?

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator:

```
def add_new_item(FUNCTION):
    def wrapper(json_file, csv_file):
        new_data = set_new_item()
        FUNCTION(json_file, csv_file)
        return new_data

    return wrapper
```

And I also have a decorated function:

```
@add_new_item
def write_csv(csv_file):
    new_data = new_data

    with open(csv_file, "a", newline="") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(new_data.values())
```

I want to use the `new_data` variable from the wrapper function in my decorated function. Is that possible?

Comment: You don't. Call `set_new_item` in the function, or accept a new parameter

Comment: Also, you call it with two parameters, but the function accepts only one

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: @CrazyChucky I have 2 functions which are: write_csv(csv_file) and write_json(json_file) both of them require the user to fill in same values. So I thought it would be a good idea to decorate them since I’m doing the same thing in both of them, which is taking users data.

Comment: It is possible to do. However the function returned from a decorator generally accepts the same arguments as the one being decorated (unlike what is in your question).

Comment: It sounds like rather than a decorator, you want a reusable data-input-getting function that each of your functions can call. As a general rule (there are always exceptions), a function should *work*, or at least do *something*, undecorated; the decorator modifies it somehow. But as currently written, your `write_csv` function by itself just doesn't work, because there's nowhere for the data to come from.